# Git. Reverting a commit older than HEAD fails

Tags: git, revert

I'm trying to learn the `git revert` command. I'm trying to revert a commit older than HEAD. Is this not allowed?

```
$ git touch sonic
$ echo sonic >> sonic
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "sonic"
$ echo the >> sonic
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "the"
$ echo hedgehog >> sonic
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "hedgehog"
$ git log --oneline
d65e56d (HEAD -> master) hedgehog
e37fefc the
c745775 sonic
```

Then

```
$ git revert HEAD^
Auto-merging sonic
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in sonic
error: could not revert e37fefc... the
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

I could do `git revert HEAD` and that would revert d65e56d but not `git revert HEAD^`. Is this simply not allowed? `git revert HEAD^^` does not work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a *failure*.  It's not a success either.  It's a *conflict*, telling you that Git was not able to resolve a problem with reverse-applying.

The conflict happened because you touched adjoining lines.  The difference between your *first* and *second* version says "add the word `the` at the end of the file, after the word `sonic`".  To undo that, Git would need to remove the word `the` at the *end of the file*, after the word `sonic`—but the file doesn't end there.  It goes on to contain the word `hedgehog` now.

In effect, Git does not know whether to remove the last line (`hedgehog`) or the line containing the word `the`.<sup>1</sup>  You might think this is obvious, but Git just doesn't know how.  So it stops with a merge conflict, and with *three* versions of the file available to you in the *index* or *staging area*, plus a *fourth* version in your work-tree, marked up with conflict markers.  It is now your job to produce the correct version of the conflicted file.

There are lots of ways to do this.  The one I tend to use is to open the work-tree file in my editor, look for the `<<<<<<<` lines, and eyeball the lines to figure out what the right thing is.  (I also set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` so that I get an extra section in the conflict area, showing me what was in the *base* version of the file as well as what was in the two conflicted versions.  In this case it doesn't really help anyway, though.)

Having edited the work-tree copy of the file down to the "right answer"—whatever that is—I write it out and exit my editor, and run `git add` on the conflicted file.  The conflict is now resolved, using what I put into it, regardless of what was in it before.

If that's the last conflict—which it will be in this case—`git revert --continue` will resume the revert and go on to any other commits you'd asked it to revert, if there were any.  Since there are no more to do, that would finish the reversion and you would be all done.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, Git is trying to merge two changes, not just delete one change.  One of the two says *remove `the`* and the other says *add `hedgehog`*.  Both go at the end of the file and Git can't figure out the right answer.

---

The failure to revert `HEAD^^` is similar, but this time the lines where Git is to remove `the` abut the lines where Git sees the addition of `sonic`.  The problem goes away if there is enough of a gap between varying lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help torek. What I did is to delete the line "the" since it is reverting "the". Now I added the file and revert --continue and it all went well!